# spinner not displaying listview items

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listfragment

I am trying to develop a listview drop down list, however, when I run the application I cannot see the listview drop down list which should show the various options from the strings.xml I have some errors while trying to implement the OnitemSelecteListener.

PlaceActivity.Java

```
public class PlaceActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


    public ArrayList<GetterSetter> myArrayList;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private Spinner spinner;
    ListView myList;
    private String[] places;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    TextView nodata;
    PlaceAdapter adapter;
    GetterSetter addValues;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_place);

        if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enable internet connection and RE-LAUNCH!!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        places = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.places);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setTitle("Title");

        spinner  = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerplaces);


        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> listAdapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(this, R.array.places,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        listAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(listAdapter);



    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null;
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int itemPosition, long itemId) {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Please wait", true);
        // Google Places Access key and location values.
        new readFromGooglePlaceAPI()
                .execute("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?"
                        + "location=53.795984,-1.759398&radius=900&sensor=true&"
                        + "key=API_Key&types="
                        + places[itemPosition]);
       myList.OnItemSelectedListener (this);
        return true;
    }


    public class readFromGooglePlaceAPI extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override protected String doInBackground(String... param) {
            return readJSON(param[0]);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String str) {
            myArrayList = new ArrayList<GetterSetter>();
            try {
                JSONObject root = new JSONObject(str);
                JSONArray results = root.getJSONArray("results");
                for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject arrayItems = results.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject geometry = arrayItems.getJSONObject("geometry");
                    JSONObject location = geometry.getJSONObject("location");
                    addValues = new GetterSetter();
                    addValues.setLat(location.getString("lat"));
                    addValues.setLon(location.getString("lng"));
                    addValues.setName(arrayItems.getString("name").toString());
                    addValues.setRating(arrayItems.getString("rating").toString());
                    addValues.setVicinity(arrayItems.getString("vicinity").toString());
                    myArrayList.add(addValues);

                    Log.d("Before", myArrayList.toString());

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            System.out
                    .println("############################################################################");
            Log.d("After:", myArrayList.toString());
            nodata = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nodata);
            nodata.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            adapter = new PlaceAdapter(PlaceActivity.this, R.layout.list_row, myArrayList);
            myList.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

    public String readJSON(String URL) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("JSON", "Couldn't find JSON file");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Intent details = new Intent(PlaceActivity.this, Details.class);
        details.putExtra("name", myArrayList.get(arg2).getName());
        details.putExtra("rating", myArrayList.get(arg2).getRating());
        details.putExtra("vicinity", myArrayList.get(arg2).getVicinity());
        details.putExtra("lat", myArrayList.get(arg2).getLat());
        details.putExtra("lon", myArrayList.get(arg2).getLon());
        startActivity(details);
    }
```

**Error 1 - Class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method on AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.**

```
public class PlaceActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
```

**Error 2 - Method does not override from its superclass.**

```
@Override public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Intent details = new Intent(PlaceActivity.this, Details.class);
        details.putExtra("name", myArrayList.get(arg2).getName());
        details.putExtra("rating", myArrayList.get(arg2).getRating());
        details.putExtra("vicinity", myArrayList.get(arg2).getVicinity());
        details.putExtra("lat", myArrayList.get(arg2).getLat());
        details.putExtra("lon", myArrayList.get(arg2).getLon());
        startActivity(details);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot add spinner.setAdapter(list); at the end of onCreate()

You can use this to implement OnItemSelectedListener:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Something like this:

```
public class PlaceActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {


public ArrayList<GetterSetter> myArrayList;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private Spinner spinner;
ListView myList;
private String[] places;
ProgressDialog dialog;
TextView nodata;
PlaceAdapter adapter;
GetterSetter addValues;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_place);

    if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enable internet connection and RE-LAUNCH!!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    places = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.places);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    setTitle("Title");

    spinner  = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerplaces);


    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> listAdapter = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(this, R.array.places,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    listAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            Intent details = new Intent(PlaceActivity.this, Details.class);
            details.putExtra("name", myArrayList.get(arg2).getName());
            details.putExtra("rating", myArrayList.get(arg2).getRating());
            details.putExtra("vicinity", myArrayList.get(arg2).getVicinity());
            details.putExtra("lat", myArrayList.get(arg2).getLat());
            details.putExtra("lon", myArrayList.get(arg2).getLon());
            startActivity(details);
        }
    });



}

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Please wait", true);
    // Google Places Access key and location values.
    new readFromGooglePlaceAPI()
            .execute("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?"
                    + "location=53.795984,-1.759398&radius=900&sensor=true&"
                    + "key=API_Key&types="
                    + places[itemPosition]);
   myList.OnItemSelectedListener (this);
    return true;
}


public class readFromGooglePlaceAPI extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override protected String doInBackground(String... param) {
        return readJSON(param[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String str) {
        myArrayList = new ArrayList<GetterSetter>();
        try {
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(str);
            JSONArray results = root.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject arrayItems = results.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject geometry = arrayItems.getJSONObject("geometry");
                JSONObject location = geometry.getJSONObject("location");
                addValues = new GetterSetter();
                addValues.setLat(location.getString("lat"));
                addValues.setLon(location.getString("lng"));
                addValues.setName(arrayItems.getString("name").toString());
                addValues.setRating(arrayItems.getString("rating").toString());
                addValues.setVicinity(arrayItems.getString("vicinity").toString());
                myArrayList.add(addValues);

                Log.d("Before", myArrayList.toString());

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        System.out
                .println("############################################################################");
        Log.d("After:", myArrayList.toString());
        nodata = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nodata);
        nodata.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        adapter = new PlaceAdapter(PlaceActivity.this, R.layout.list_row, myArrayList);
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

}

public String readJSON(String URL) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("JSON", "Couldn't find JSON file");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: I have added that now, but still same issue.

Comment: If your want to implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener in your class, you need to override both methods: onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) and  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent).

Comment: could you please show me example as I have already tried this and still getting errors. I have used the official Android documentary spinner which I have tried and still not working. Please can you rewrite my code.

Comment: Can you show me how I can implement these methods into my code. I want the code to display a list and then it will show them googleplaces details once selected option from list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Replace the following lines from onCreate event in PlaceActivity

```
spinner  = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerplaces);    

        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> listAdapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(this, R.array.places,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        listAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

by this

```
spinner  = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerplaces);

        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.places));

        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Please wait", true);
                // Google Places Access key and location values.
                new readFromGooglePlaceAPI()
                        .execute("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?"
                                + "location=53.795984,-1.759398&radius=900&sensor=true&"
                                + "key=API_Key&types="
                                + places[itemPosition]);
                myList.OnItemSelectedListener (this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                Intent details = new Intent(PlaceActivity.this, Details.class);
                details.putExtra("name", myArrayList.get(arg2).getName());
                details.putExtra("rating", myArrayList.get(arg2).getRating());
                details.putExtra("vicinity", myArrayList.get(arg2).getVicinity());
                details.putExtra("lat", myArrayList.get(arg2).getLat());
                details.putExtra("lon", myArrayList.get(arg2).getLon());
                startActivity(details);
            }

        });
```

And remove "implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener" from PlaceActivity.

Also remove following 2 method, you are handled outside the onCreate event

```
@Override public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Intent details = new Intent(PlaceActivity.this, Details.class);
        details.putExtra("name", myArrayList.get(arg2).getName());
        details.putExtra("rating", myArrayList.get(arg2).getRating());
        details.putExtra("vicinity", myArrayList.get(arg2).getVicinity());
        details.putExtra("lat", myArrayList.get(arg2).getLat());
        details.putExtra("lon", myArrayList.get(arg2).getLon());
        startActivity(details);
    }
```

and

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Please wait", true);
    // Google Places Access key and location values.
    new readFromGooglePlaceAPI()
            .execute("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?"
                    + "location=53.795984,-1.759398&radius=900&sensor=true&"
                    + "key=API_Key&types="
                    + places[itemPosition]);
   myList.OnItemSelectedListener (this);
    return true;
}
```